# Help understanding a homework problem (Preconditioning matrices, numerical methods)

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, finite-element-method

Below is a link to the problem (because I didn't want to have to go through the pain of TeXing it all out myself), the basic idea is we are supposed to be first showing that a specific matrix has a bounded condition number and then bounding some (seemingly random to me) quotient.

My problem is that I don't fully understand how to go about doing this sort of thing. Yes, there are hints given as to how to accomplish the tasks, but the hints confuse me as much as the original problem. Can anyone give me any insight/hints/tips/ideas on how to go about solving this thing? Thanks in advance.

[Link to the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvku9.png)

Comment: What part of it can you do? This is quite a long problem so we certainly cannot even sketch a solution for the whole thing.

Comment: I can use a reference triangle and show that the a-hat operator is bounded, but other than that I'm at a loss.